# Comparação de valor dentro de data frame

Tags: r, array, lógica, for, condição

Olá, tenho um banco de dados, com cerca de 50000 observação, da seguinte forma, valores apenas figurativos:

```
nome<-c("joão","pedro", "joãoo")
identificador<-c(123456,124578,123456)
valor<-c(2145,350,23)
dados=data.frame(nome,identificador,valor)
```

gostaria de identificar indivíduos com o mesmo identificador e criar uma nova variável da seguinte forma:

```
nome=c("joão","pedro", "joãoo","maria","mariaa","carla","felipe","vitor","pedro","vitorr")
identificador=c(123456,124578,123456,000,000,123,156,2222,3232,2222)
valor=c(2145,350,23,32,12,32,1,2,54,4)'
validor=c(1,0,1,2,2,0,0,3,0,3)
dados=data.frame(nome,identificador,valor,validor)
```

fiz dessa forma para identificar os identificadores iguais, mas n conseguir fazer essa variável.

```
x<-dados$identificador
length(x)
i=1
k=1
validor=0
validor[1:50000]=0
for(i in 1:50000){
  for(j  in 1:50000){
    if(x[j]==x[i] & i!= j ){
      validor[j]=k
    }
  }
}
```

gostaria de criar uma função que produzisse a variável validor da forma que foi mostrada.
Espero ter sido claro, e desde já agradeço muito a ajuda.

Comment: Onde está `dados`? Acho que você deveria ter passado o *dataframe* para a variável dados: `dados = data.frame(...` - o igual funcional como o `<-`, só que é um caractere a menos, por isso gosto de usar. Qual o resultado que você espera?

Comment: editei, gostaria de criar a variável "validor" identificando os pares,ou conjunto, de identificador com um algorismos

Comment: Você pode explicar como esta sequencia é formada? `validor = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3)`. Ao que me parece você criou um vetor com a ordem em que os números se repetem. E.g.: **123456** é o primeiro a repetir, **000** é o segundo a repetir e, por último, **2222** é o terceiro a repetir, portanto, equivalem a 1, 2 e 3, respectivamente. Os outros não repetem, por isso, recebem 0.

Comment: exatamente isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que isso é muito próximo do que você quer. A diferença é que os identificadores iguais não estarão nessa ordem:1,2,3...

```
library(uniqueAtomMat)
library(tuple)
identificador<-c(123456,124578,123456,000,000,123,156,2222,3232,2222)
validor<-grpDuplicated(identificador) # agrupa idenficadores iguais dentro de uma mesma categoria
validor[match(orphan(validor),validor)]<-0  #Atribui zero aos identificaores órfãos.
```